# How to check data is submitted in form, or in query string in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a handler in my ASP.NET Core Razor Page:

```
public IActionResult OnPostDoSomething()
{
    // How can I know that the data is sent in query string, or in form, or in headers?
}
```

This method is called from multiple places, and each calls it differently. One via a form, the other via an AJAX call and sends parameters in query string.

I know I can check `if (Request.Query["key"].Count > 0)` and based on this understand which method has been used.

But I wonder if ASP.NET Core Razor Pages has a built-in technology to let me know that a form
exists or not. For example something like `if (Request.FormExists)`.

The reason I'm looking for a dynamic solution, is because I'm building a dynamic code and I don't have access to the name of the parameters being sent.

Is there a way for that?

Comment: If you want to know whether it's a `GET` or `POST` request, check [the `Request.Method` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.method?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: This post may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055131/net-core-middleware-getting-form-data-from-request

Answer (score 3):

Good,
you can always use the snippet `context.Request.HasFormContentType`, to check if there is a form attached to the request.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wonder if ASP.NET Core Razor Pages has a built-in technology to let me know that a form exists or not.

If you want to know if the request is sent by form,you can try to check `content-type` in headers:

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["content-type"].ToString().Equals("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) {
                //request is sent by a form
            }
```